# jquery using php as a selector

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Hi I am trying to make a hidden div appear on hover to cover my image and I have a list that is dynamically generated from project posts in wordpress..obviously the list class names are all different..

What would my selector be so that the div appears just on the list item hovered.

```
<li class="item-<?php the_ID() ?> <?php if(++$count%4==0) echo 'rightmost'?> ">
                        <div class="image">
                            <span>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                    <?php
                                        if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                                            the_post_thumbnail('post-thumb');
                                        }
                                    ?>

                                </a>
                            </span>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="link">View Details</a>                    
                        </div>
<div class="content">
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>
                            <span class="tags">
                                <?php 
                                    // Fetching the tag names with respect to the post and displaying them
                                    $args =   array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'names');
                                    echo implode(wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'tag', $args),', '); 
                                ?>
                            </span>
                            <p>
                                <?php 
                                    // Using custom excerpt function to fetch the excerpt
                                    folio_excerpt('folio_excerpt_length','folio_excerpt_more');
                                 ?>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </li>                                   
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>   


<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.item-<?php the_ID() ?>').hover(
            function(){ 
            $('#folio li .content').fadeIn();
        },

            function() {
            $("#folio li .content").fadeOut();
            });
});

</script>
```

http://allavitart.yourtrioproject.com/portfolio/
thats my poopie work in progress

Comment: what jquery code have you tried? and why can't you just use `.image`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery provides multiple ways to traverse the DOM, so this can be achieved with multiple solutions, here's one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#folio li').hover(function(){ 
            $(this).find('.content').fadeIn();
        },function() {
            $(this).find('.content').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: If the above doesn't work than check your browser console (Ctrl+Shift+J) and fix any errors you encounter

Comment: that worked! but go to the website and now look at my issue when you hover it

Comment: @Blake yes I was actually just thinking you were going to face that problem, check the update I made above, use the list item instead of the `.image` to trigger the events

Comment: yeah i tested that one already and then it doesnt seem to work

Comment: correction you are the man! didnt see the .find..thank you so muchh!

Answer (score 0):

well by reviewing your code i see there is a container that have id `folio`.

we use that:

```
jQuery("#folio ul li").hover(function(){ 
    jQuery(this).children("span").fadeOut(); 
});
```

Is that Solving your problem?

Comment: Important: the second line is example. i don't know what exactly you want to do when user hovers over the li.

Comment: check out the site now it is updated and you can see my problem..http://allavitart.yourtrioproject.com/portfolio/

Answer (score 0):

You could store your id `the_id` in a data attribute, then have one class you can use for the jQuery selector, like:

HTML:

```
<li class="hover" data-id="<? the_id() ?>" …
```

jQuery:

```
$(".hover").hover(function() {
    // Do something with id, show div, etc.
});
```

Comment: I set my line to <li data-id="<?php the_ID() ?>" class="port-hover item-<?php the_ID() ?> <?php if(++$count%4==0) echo 'rightmost'?> "> and then my jquery to $('.port-hover').hover(function(){ function(){$('#folio li .content').fadeIn();}, but it still isnt working

Comment: @Blake post the complete markup (with `.content`) along with your jquery code in your question, so we get exactly what you're trying to do, if what you commented above is your actual code then there's a problem with having `function(){ function()`